# Why is this NSArray not working? I'm trying to add objects to it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray

I'm trying to add objects to this NSArray (labelArray) but for some reason, it returns as (null) in NSLog every time, and the count remains at 0.

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(howFarAlong, howFarDown, 50, 70)];
label.text = @"text";
[self.view addSubview:label];
[labelArray addObject:label];
NSLog(@"%@", labelArray);
[label release];
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you `init` your `NSMutableArray *labelArray`?

Comment: not xcode-related. check for the usage of the tag [xcode]: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xcode/info

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An `NSArray` is immutable. If you want to call `-addObject:`, use `NSMutableArray`. If `labelArray` is an `NSArray`, then that should crash. If it doesn’t crash, then it’s probably `nil`, and you haven’t initialized it. Some code that *will* work:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(howFarAlong, howFarDown, 50, 70)];
label.text = @"text";
[self.view addSubview:label];

if (labelArray == nil) {
    labelArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

[labelArray addObject:label];
NSLog(@"%@", labelArray);
[label release];
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an NSMutableArray if you want to change the data in your array. NSArray can only be used to create static arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You probably also receive a message from the compiler stating that NSArray may not respond to 'addObjext'. This is your clue that the object you are using won't perform the requested selector (method). In this case, you are trying to change an immutable object, which won't work. You need to use an NSMutableArray. I suggest you read up on the differences in Apple's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code below.  The count is 1 after the lable is added.

```
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(howFarAlong, howFarDown, 50, 70)];
    label.text = @"text";
    [self.view addSubview:label];

    NSArray *labelArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:label];  
    NSLog(@"Count: %d", labelArray.count);
```